# onblur and link elements not working properly in Chrome - Fine in IE 10

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to achieve the following.  Click on a link, display menu.  As soon as that menu loses focus, clear the menu (also when menu item is clicked, remove the menu).

Here is my dumbed down code:

```
    <a id="owner" href="javascript: doThis();" onblur="remove();">ClickOnMe</a>

    function doThis() { console.log('clickedOnItem'); }

    function remove() { console.log('removed'); }
```

I can't seem to get this to work.  It works fine in IE10, but I can't get to work in Chrome.

Fiddle me this: http://jsfiddle.net/5t6wr/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason chrome isn't registering your link as a focused item.  What we have to do is force the link to be focused so chrome recognizes it.

Change your link to the following:

```
<a id="owner" href="javascript: document.getElementById('owner').focus(); doThis();" >ClickOnMe</a>
```

We added the focus to owner, then proceeded with your function to bring up the menu.

Inside your doThis function you will want to add the following:

```
document.activeElement.onblur = function() { remove(); };
```

That is going to take the current Active Element - and when focus is lost, run your script to close the window.

Note:  You should put your remove function on a timeout, as you will be loading something from the menu, and don't want to have both trigger at the same time, it will cause a conflict.

Here is a fiddle to see the final version:
http://jsfiddle.net/5t6wr/4/

Comment: This saved me from a frustrating afternoon. Thanks!