# Make Dropdown menu Disappear

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a code from W3schools, in which we get dropdown menu after clicked on a button.

Dropdown menu don't disappear when we click anywhere else.
I have surfed a bit but it seems confusing as am new to js.

It would be much helpful if anyone could suggest how do we make it disappear?

[Code Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_dropdown)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code somewhere:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
};
```

The original code that you wrote triggers the addition or removal of the "show" class on the element of id "myBtn" only when this element itself is clicked:

> document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {
>       document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
>     };

But it does nothing if you click outside, that's the role of the `onblur` event.

Comment: how can we use this for <a> instead of button?

Comment: Give the element an id, for example <a id="myBtn">. It will work the same way as the div.

Comment: u mean just change <button> to <a> in above case?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Tags such as input, button, a, div, span actually just give default CSS to the content, and their editing differ, but these are only nodes with the same events which can be attached. Try it.

Comment: Indeed, good catch. Depending on the browser, clicking on a link does not provide it focus by default (in Chrome, not in IE). Hence you need to modify the HTML of the button to:
`<a id="myBtn" class="dropbtn" href="javascript: document.getElementById('myBtn').focus()">Dropdown</a>`

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529797/onblur-and-link-elements-not-working-properly-in-chrome-fine-in-ie-10

Comment: Its not allowing to click on links on dropdown menu. making it disappear on click. https://jsfiddle.net/r0xk9yfs/5/

Comment: Yes, as soon as you click on the dropdown menu, an `onblur` event is sent so the dropdown menu is closed. What you can do is either ask a whole new question on Stack Overflow, or modify the code in the onblur so that if the focus is on an element inside the dropdown, it does not cause the closing of the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
// Get the button, and when the user clicks on it, execute myFunction
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {
  myFunction()
};
document.getElementById("myBtn").onblur = function() {
  myFunction();
};

/* myFunction toggles between adding and removing the show class, which is used to hide and show the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work in general, try hitting "tab" to select the dropdown button, and then click somewhere else, you'll see the dropdown to appear.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer yes it is a little broken, but it partially addresses the question to give idea of **toggling** classes and reusing the same function

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").onblur = function(){
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove('show')
};
```

"onBlur" is the Event for losing the focus